# Binance API. Is it possible to get the value that a pair was trading on a certain date and time?

Tags: php, api, binance

Using Binance's API, is it possible to get the value that a pair was trading on a certain date and time? I need to get, for example, the value of BTC/USDT (and other pairs) on 2019-11-27 at 15:39:07 and other dates. I thought of a function that would receive the pair and timestamp parameters, like:

myFunc( pair, timestamp){
...
return price; }

```
app.get( "/api/pastPrice", async function( req, res ){
    var symbol = req.query.pair;
    var start = req.query.start;
    var end = req.query.end;

    var price = await api.pastPrice( symbol, interval = '1m', startTime = start, endTime = end, limit = 500 );

    res.send( price );
    console.info( price );
});

async function pastPrice( symbol, interval, startTime, endTime, limit ){
    return publicCall( "/v3/klines", { symbol: symbol, interval: interval, startTime: startTime, endTime: endTime, limit: limit }, "GET", "api" );
}

async function publicCall(path, data = {}, method = 'GET') {
    try {
    
        const qs = data ? `?${queryString.stringify(data)}` : '';
        const result = await axios({
            method,
            url: `${apiUrl}${path}${qs}`
        });
        return result.data;
    } 
    catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}
```

I tried to adapt to use klines (I only inform the symbol, startTime and limit parameters, and in limit I pass the value 1), but I need to provide an exact date.

Comment: What if you just pass the start time and use the 'open' value?

Comment: @Evert, I'm using open as you said, but it's not an accurate result. This becomes clear when I compare the "open time" returned, which is different from the startTime sent as a parameter in klines (that is, I send a request for a date/time and get a return for another date/time). I understand that if "open time" were the same value as startTime, it would be correct. Any tips? Thanks